# Экранрование символов JQuery

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, frontend, сопоставление-с-образцом

у меня есть вот такая функция `e.target.id.replace(/]/g, '\\]')` - она экранирует один символ `]` Я не силен в этих всех ругулярных правилах. Помогите добавить в эту функцию экранирование остальных символов:
`*, @, #, $, %, ^, &, ?, !, (, ), [, ], {, }, |, <, >, ~, \, /, ", ',`

Comment: и для каких целей вы пытаетесь экранировать эти символы? в какой задаче все из вышеперечисленного имеет спец. значения, что это необходимо экранировать. Более того, там где возникает потребность экранировать в большинстве случаев библиотеки предоставляю функционал экранирования, для этого не надо городить регулярки.

Comment: @teran  довольно исчерпывающий ответ